# PayPal CUSTREF Not Appearing in PayFlow Pro Transactions with Secure Token (Transparent Redirect)

Tags: paypal, payflowpro

I'm using PayPal PayFlow Pro to process transactions. We've opted to use the secure token with transparent redirects to try and address PCI-Compliance issues.

In my token request, I am specifying the CUSTREF parameter like so:

```
&CUSTREF=461
```

I have also created a hidden field for this in the transaction form. I have the HTTPS proxy enabled for Fiddler and I can see these values coming through in both the secure token and transaction requests. The transactions complete successfully on the live PayFlow gateway.

However, when I view the transactions under https://manager.paypal.com/ > Reports > Daily Activity, the *Cust Ref #:* field on the detail page is empty.

The parameter is discussed for use in inquiry transactions on page 71 of this document:
https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/payflowgateway_guide.pdf

I couldn't find much documentation on this field other than this. I had a look at some code samples, and it looks like the CUSTREF parameter should be passed in the transaction request (which was the first thing I tried), e.g.

https://github.com/angelleye/paypal/blob/master/PayFlowTransaction.php

Has anyone encountered this before? I have a ticket open with PayPal.

Comment: What is the ticket? I can take a look at it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that I have this issue open with a PayPal engineer that I have been working with. I'll try and get a ticket for you.

Comment: I have opened a ticket: SAXK (KMM92510710V4213L0KM) :ppNA

Comment: That is a ticket number for our Merchant Solutions team. A Merchant Technical Services ticket would be filed here - PayPal.com/MTS. The ticket number would be formatted like this - 130718-000000

Comment: Hello Patrick - I have submitted ticket #130720-000027.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received confirmation from PayPal that this is a bug.

This appears to work with the regular Payflow Pro API calls, but fails when passing the CUSTREF using a Secure Token API call or hosted pages (using Secure Token).

The recommended work-around was to pass the field through in the comments.